# Nested async execution is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function will send all the images that located inside the "samples" folder to extractImage function, then, the extractImage function will call 3rd party API to perform its operation. But when I try to console.log(arr), it seem like didn't even be called. I think I have did something wrong to handling the async, could someone help me to have a look. I have quick new to JavaScript.

```
let arr = [];

await fs.readdir("samples", async (err, files) => {
  console.log(files);
  files.map(async (val) => {
    console.log(val);
    let tt = await extractImage(val);
    return arr.push(tt);
  });
});

fs.writeFileSync("final.json", "s");

console.log(arr);
console.log("tt");
```

Comment: That first await is not inside an async function, so it won't give the desired outcome

Comment: You didn't use fs.readdir() correctly, and it should be `const files = await readdir(path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use fs.readdir() correctly, and it should be `const files = await readdir(path)`. And your `files.map(async (val) => {...})` will return a list of promises immediately, and `console.log(arr)` might be executed even before these promises resolve. The code might be like the following one:

```
let files = await fs.readdir("samples")
console.log(files);

let promises = files.map(async (val) => {
    let tt = await extractImage(val);
    return tt;
});

let arr = await Promise.all(promises)
console.log(arr);
console.log("tt");

fs.writeFileSync("final.json", "s");
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

1. `await` cannot be used in a global context.
2. `fs.readdir` does not return a promise. It is callback based, which means you cannot await it. However, there is  a synchronous version of the method: `fs.readdirSync`.
3. As of Node 11, you can do this:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
```

which allows the use of await and .then on fs. For lower versions, you can use `util.promisify`.

Comment: As I checked, the fs.readdir() does not support .then()

Answer (score 1):

I might consider using [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) in this instance, and then returning an array of promises from the files, and getting your data when all of those have been resolved.

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const readdirP = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

async function main() {
  try {
    const files = await readdirP('samples');
    const promises = files.map(file => extractImage(file));
    const data = await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Using a self-invoked function could help in this case:**

```
(async function () {
  let arr = [];
  await fs.readdir("samples", async (err, files) => {
    console.log(files);
    files.map(async (val) => {
      console.log(val);
      let tt = await extractImage(val);
      return arr.push(tt);
    });
  });
  fs.writeFileSync("final.json", "s");
  console.log(arr);
  console.log("tt");
});
```

Comment: I have tested this solution before but it seem like the console.log(arr); didn't wait for fs.readdir() to complete